# Pros & cons of including requesting IP address in password reset emails?

Tags: privacy, password-reset

It has crossed my mind to include the requesting IP address in password reset emails. The intention being that if someone is receiving unexpected reset emails, this allows them to do a basic level of investigation. Ok, people can hide their IP address using a VPN, but for low-level attacks this is unlikely to happen.

There's a potential privacy issue in that someone's IP address is normally private. But if you're putting someone else's email into a reset process, do you have any real expectation of privacy? There could be text on the page warning people of this - in fact, just the text alone would be a deterrent.

Anyway, it seems reasonable to me but my mind isn't made up, so I'm interested in what other people perceive as the pros and cons of doing this.

Comment: It depends on who’ll get the emails. Do they even know their public IP? What percentage will confuse it with their local IP (usually 192.168.x.y)? Will it generate more confusion than without it? Maybe make it optional to get this information (for example by offering to login in a website to investigate the matter).

Comment: On a legitimate request, the IP address will be sent to its owner, so there’s not privacy issue. In case of an illegitimate request, I’m not sure the law would protect the privacy of the attacker, and there is a legitimate need for the service and its customers to disclose the IP address. The question remains for when the password reset was triggered by mistake, for example by someone who wrongly typed its email.

Comment: Don't forget cases where a user is on a VPN or remote (virtual) machine and the IP address won't be what is expected and can even be in a different part of the country/world from what they would expect.

Comment: What sort of investigation are you talking about?    What possible results do you expect from the investigation?   What actions do you expect the user to take?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat - Light touch investigation, just figuring out if it's a bot farm in China or someone local. If the emails are recurring and a concern, action could include changing the registered email used on the site.

Comment: I like the way google etc do it, along the lines of "this request came from OS in City, State"

Comment: The general recommendation is to delete unexpected "password reset" emails without even opening them, so the more security-conscious users you have in mind may never see the contents of the email in the first place.

Comment: You could not include it in the email, but display it on the website after authentication in an audit log of attempted accesses/resets.

Comment: Depending on the population, they may not even know what an IP is (not to mention knowing *their* external IP which is expert knowledge). You could geolocate the IP but this can have legal consequences (at least in the EU where we have GDPR)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> if you're putting someone else's email into a reset process, do you
> have any real expectation of privacy?

This statement is based on the idea that putting someone else's email into a reset process is malicious. What about "fat fingers"? Or people making a mistake about what email or account is theirs?

My personal email address is generic and I deal with "schroeders" around the world mistaking my address for theirs. Including multiple password resets on multiple accounts. Some of which I didn't even set up.

So, by placing their IP in the email, I gain far more info than I should have about them (even more than knowing that they signed up for "gun-toting furry" matchmaking sites (not kidding)).

Investigations should go through the service after proper authentication.

Comment: I agree not just about IP addresses but also about anything other than the minimum required to complete the reset process. I also get lots of email for people with similar addresses. Someone else's password reset email for a "clown supplies" site once leaked that person's IP, full name, location, mobile phone platform/version, preferred web browser, and employer. More than enough to start a targeted malware attack. It's a completely unnecessary risk.

Answer (score 13):

> The intention being that if someone is receiving unexpected reset emails, this allows them to do a basic level of investigation

I would question whether a full IP address is the best solution to this problem.

For a few more technical users it could be helpful, but for the vast majority of people they have no idea what it means. Whereas something like a rough geographic location (as Microsoft can do for their MFA) might give them a more useful indication - with the usual caveats about the fact that it's not bulletproof.

Alternatively, perhaps you could show the first three octets of the IP address and mask the fourth? That should give most users enough to determine whether it was them or not, without providing the full IP address.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is against privacy laws in addition to the other answers. California’s privacy law considers IP addresses as Personally Identifiable Information (PII) if used as an attempt to identify users (phrased this way as to avoid the fact the most of the internet stack operates via IP addresses). Thus, by including an IP that you believe isn’t of the owner of the account for the sake of having it be an identifier for the individual placing the request is basically just sending PII to out to random users.

See this page for more information:
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67542/are-there-privacy-laws-other-than-gdpr-which-consider-ip-addresses-as-personal-d

Comment: This doesn't seem reasonable to me. The link provided does not state that IP addresses by themselves are definitely PII, only that they may be in some cases when they can be combined with other information. Sending an arbitrary IP address to someone is not the same thing as collecting and storing a bunch of IP addresses. Also, even that cannot be itself illegal, or else DNS, DHCP, BGP etc would immediately be outlawed, bringing down the internet itself and creating worldwide chaos and economic collapse.

Comment: @barbecue, as the answer there mentioned, it isn't fully clear. However, a general agreement is that IP can be PII if a legal method of tracing the IP back to the individual, or by another other means to trace it back to the individual, can be utilized. Knowing the IP of the user and the site, in addition to the time, is enough to potentially be PII if there is any possibility for tracing it back to the individual, whether that be that legal means or not. In the case one could even argue that an individual may create a legal case that compels an ISP.

Comment: @barbecue, but even if we assume no legal means, what if we assume a user crossover, a typo in their email? If a users email is their name, and the name itself is relatively unique, you could potentially assign the IP to a specific user just through the email association alone. Yep, PII definitions are vague, but it seems pretty clear that most would consider it PII, just depends on the circumstances.

Comment: It just seems like a huge overreach to me, I can't imagine something like this standing up in actual court.

Comment: It can be illegal in countries applying GDPR: IP address is [explicitly "online identifier"](https://gdpr.eu/recital-30-online-identifiers-for-profiling-and-identification/) hence in scope for personal data protection, so transmitting it in email [requires encryption](https://gdpr.eu/email-encryption/) which is not possible for an arbitrary email address.